# How to remove some leading characters of a string which is an element of a list in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, character

I got an email address list from one of my colleagues like -

`listNew = ['john.smith@hotmail.com', 'Tom White <tom.white@gmail.com', '<connie.green@yahoo.com']`

How can I remove the '`<`' and all the characters before '`<`' in some address element of the list with Python, please?

Comment: Look at `str.partition()` as in `list[1].partition("<")[-1]`. Or `list[1].partition("<")[0]` if there is no `<`. But please don't use `list` as a variable...sooner or later it will come back to bite you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list1 = ['john.smith@hotmail.com', 'Tom White <tom.white@gmail.com', '<connie.green@yahoo.com']
for i in range(len(list1)):
    list1[i]=list1[i].split('<')[-1]
print(list1)
```

Comment: they specifically want _and all the characters before_, so only the split version will work

Answer (score 2):

call `.split()` and take the last part!

as a list comprehension

```py
[value.split("<")[-1] for value in original_values]
```

If you want *both* any available name and the address, use a dedicated library, which can also handle the troublesome edges around email address validity
https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.utils.html#email.utils.parseaddr

```py
>>> from email.utils import parseaddr
>>> parseaddr("foo <bar.baz@example.com")  # easily handles missing '>'
('foo', 'bar.baz@example.com')
```

all together

```py
from email.utils import parseaddr

def parse_emails_to_pairs(emails_list):
    for email_str in emails_list:
        name, email = parseaddr(email_str)
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(f"couldn't parse email {email_str}")
        yield (name or None, email)
```

```py
>>> list(parse_emails_to_pairs(['john.smith@hotmail.com', 'Tom White <tom.white@gmail.com', '<connie.green@yahoo.com']))
[(None, 'john.smith@hotmail.com'), ('Tom White', 'tom.white@gmail.com'), (None, 'connie.green@yahoo.com')]
```

also beware that that naming your list literally `list` is poor practice because it'll clobber `list()` and potentially confuse future readers within that scope! (though it may not matter for your case)

Comment: split worked perfectly! Thank you very much for your prompt reply!
Could you kindly further correct my following code, please?
```

Comment: ```# remove < sign and everything before it
    listNew2 = []
    for e in listNew:
        eNew = ''
        if '<' in e:
            eTmp = ''
            eTmp = e.split('<', 1)
            eNew = eTmp[1]
        else:
            eNew = e
        listNew2.append(eNew)
   ```

Comment: @ShermanChen you can actually dodge any need to do that because `.split()[-1]` still works even if there wasn't a match! (first creating a list a list with just one entry, and then taking it) .. if you want to get the names _if they exist_ or do more email handling, use a library https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.utils.html#email.utils.parseaddr

Comment: ti7, I am sorry I am a python beginner. I know that your reply is a perfect and advanced one! (thumb up)

Comment: @ShermanChen not to worry; everyone starts out somewhere and nothing is perfect, just good enough for a purpose! this is a bit dated, but very insightful if you wanted a good read! https://david.goodger.org/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use the map() method with the array, then apply replace() to each array item by passing them in with the lambda function.

```
list = ['john.smith@hotmail.com', 'Tom White <tom.white@gmail.com', '<connie.green@yahoo.com']

list = map(lambda email: email.replace("<", ""), list)

print(list)
```

EDIT: Didn't see that you wanted to remove all leading, not just the <, in that case you can use the find() function on the strings:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(list):
    print(list[idx])
    if val.find('<') >= 0:
        list[idx] = val[val.find('<')+1:len(val)]
    else: 
        list[idx] = val
print(list)
```